# Shouldn't we have a "Sankhara" tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

Snaskara or Sankhara is a commonly used term in both questons and answers so wouldn't it be nice to have a Tag for it?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot create tags independently on this site. They should be created when asking the question by users who has enough privileges to do this. I believe you wanted this tag added to the following question: [What is the process that creates "Saṅkhāra"](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/12891/what-is-the-process-that-creates-sa%E1%B9%85kh%C4%81ra), which I have done. This would add the tag to the list of tags for future use.

Comment: Thanks Suminda!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I have an answer but here are a few thoughts.

---

Tags aren't really important for single well-defined words. Take "dukkha" for example: you can find lots of posts by [searching for 'dukkha'](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/search?q=dukkha) ... because it's easy to search it isn't very necessary to have a tag.

Tags are useful though for the following purposes:

- Searching doesn't work because of translations -- a post might contain the word 'dukkha' or 'suffering' so it's good to have a tag (see also [What language should our tags be in?](https://buddhism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2/254))
- Tags are good for categorizing -- for example a question about alcohol might be tagged with 'addiction', 'precepts', 'sila', etc.
- Tags are good for schools -- we try to use 'theravada' or 'mahayana' etc. for example when we want the answers to reflect the orthodox perspective from one specific school
- Tags might be useful for users to 'favourite' or 'ignore' -- for example I might decide I never want to read questions which are tagged 'science' or 'kamma', in which case I could add those tags to the list of topics I won't see, in my user profile

A while ago I sanitized the tags on meta (i.e. reviewed and edited every topics to ensure its tags made sense) so I think that all the tags on meta are used in a regular/predictable way.

People haven't done that same job on the main site, so the use of tags there is hap-hazard and random, with people adding tags whenever they feel like it, not using existing tags, not knowing what the existing tags are, not having a grand plan for the way in which tags ought to be used, and so I don't find the existing tags-in-general there very useful/understandable/reliable.

The one bit of clean-up that has ever happened so far is that @CrabBucket reviewed and retagged all the meditation topics/tags (see [Proposal for retagging meditation questions](https://buddhism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1551/254) and corresponding chat in the chat room plus CrabBucket's corresponding edits to topics).

Comment: thanks for the answer, you got a good point here.